# Firebase Auth Emulator Failing (auth/network-request-failed)

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, expo

I am developing a react native app using expo and firebase and am trying to set up the local emulator for testing/debugging. Creating accounts and logging in/logging out work on the actual database, but when I run these functions with the auth emulator attached, I get the following:

```
Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).
at [native code]:null in construct
at [native code]:null in construct
at node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:348:0 in <global>
at http://192.168.1.187:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:182911:26 in FirebaseError
at node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.esm2017.js:564:0 in <global>
at node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:283:4 in <anonymous>
at http://192.168.1.187:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:185674:17 in <unknown>
at node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:103:8 in Logger
at node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:3:54 in <global>
at http://192.168.1.187:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:184314:35 in rejected
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

This occurs on both an android pixel 5 emulator and my actual phone (galaxy s8+).
Other solutions for this error seem to be for browser security reasons (i.e. CORS), but that doesn't seem to be applicable here. The code connecting to the emulator is:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth, connectAuthEmulator} from "firebase/auth";
import {getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator} from "firebase/firestore";
import {getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator} from "firebase/functions";

const firebaseConfig = {/* config object */};

const fbApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const fbAuth = getAuth(fbApp);
connectAuthEmulator(fbAuth, "http://localhost:9099");
export const fbFunctions = getFunctions(fbApp);
connectFunctionsEmulator(fbFunctions, 'localhost', 5001);
export const db = getFirestore(fbApp);
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);
```

The port is correct and the emulator interface shows that auth is running fine.

Comment: do you have `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies This was the issue. Unfortunately, I'm using the expo managed workflow so it's not possible to set this property trivially. For now, using ngrok to get an https link works, but hopefully I'll find a better solution at some point.

Comment: it would be so great of you to answer your own question, facing the exact same issue.